# Django: returning empty {} with 400 Bad request for post method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to implement an attendance system as part of a bigger project that handles multiple schools at the same time but the endpoint is returning an empty `{}` with a `400_BAD_REQUEST`

**Attendance/models.py**

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
Choices = (
    ("P", "Present"),
    ("A", "Absent"),
    ("L", "On leave"),
)

user = models.ForeignKey(
    User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_attendance", blank=False, null=True)
leave_reason = models.CharField(max_length=355, blank=True, null=True)
Date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=True,
                        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
Presence = models.CharField(
    choices=Choices, max_length=255, blank=False, null=True)
attendance_taker = models.ForeignKey(
    User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="attendance_taker_attendance", blank=False, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user}'

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("Attendance")
    verbose_name_plural = _("Attendance")
    constraints = [
        UniqueConstraint(
            fields=('user', 'Date'), name='unique_attendance_once_per_date')
    ]
```

**Attendance/serializers.py**

```
class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Attendance
    fields = ['user', 'Presence', 'leave_reason', 'Date']
    constraints = [
        UniqueConstraint(
            fields=('user', 'Date'), name='unique_attendance_once_per_date')
    ]

def create(self, validated_data):
    instance = Attendance.objects.create(
        user=validated_data['user'],
        Presence=validated_data['Presence'],
        leave_reason=validated_data['leave_reason'],
        attendance_taker=self.context['request'].user,
        Date=datetime.today
    )
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

**Attendance/views.py**

```
class AttendanceListCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
permission_classes = [IsClassPart]
queryset = Attendance.objects.all()
serializer_class = AttendanceSerializer

def post(self, request, format=None):
    user = request.user
    try:
        perms = Perm.objects.get(user=user)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        perms = None
    serializer = AttendanceSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        if user.role == "TEACHER":
            if user.homeroom == serializer.validated_data['user'].room:
                Response({"message": "You don't have permission to perform this action 1"},
                         status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        elif perms is not None:
            if user.role != 'STUDENT' and user.perms.is_monitor:
                if user.room != serializer.validated_data['user'].room:
                    Response({"message": "You don't have permission to perform this action 2"},
                             status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({"message": "You don't have permission to perform this action 3"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Postman test request**

[image: As you can see I'm sending user id, Presence=L(represents on leave) and leave_reason but the endpoint returns an empty {}]

Comment: Can you add how Perm model looks?

Comment: i have edited it in.

Comment: Sorry, can you also provide User model?

Comment: i have edited it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont understand why you don't use user.has_perms(), but you forget any return on the if else block with perms check:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    user = request.user
    serializer = AttendanceSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        if user.role == "TEACHER":
            if user.homeroom == serializer.validated_data['user'].room:
                # Here error, without return
                return Response({"message": "You don't have permission to perform this action 1"},
                     status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        elif user.get_all_permissions():
            if user.role != 'STUDENT' and user.perms.is_monitor:
                if user.room != serializer.validated_data['user'].room:
                    # ERROR probably 
                    return Response({"message": "You don't have permission to perform this action 2"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
             # error probably here too

        else:
            return Response({"message": "You don't have permission to perform this action 3"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I fixed the issues you listed but the error persists.

Comment: for teacher the same error, your function is too complex, because you can not fint your errors yourself. I fix the answer. And please, read about Django-GCBV

Comment: So does the has_perms function handle complex validation like this? i don't like my way of implementation either but i was not sure that the default Django permissions could handle validation based on data on another table

Comment: @redietyosef - you simply don't understand permissions backend in django.contrib.auth.backends. Permissions, your role, custom_permissons like is_monitor can be completely in other databases,not only tables.

Comment: yes you are right i don't understand it, can you point me to some resources???

Comment: i don't see any good resources about it. Here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends, but it is not easy to use for developer, i know.  Probably if you start to implement something like custom user.backend, you can ask about it here?